# Makefile not detecting dependency change

Tags: c, makefile

I have a Makefile to help build my C project (GNU Make 3.82). Here's just a snippet:

```
OBJ = file1.o file2.o file3.o

prog: $(OBJ)
    $(COMP) $(OPT) -o $@

$(OBJ): header.h
```

`$(OBJ)` doesn't need a command after it since `make` is able to work it out like its doing in the rest of the Makefile. All objects are dependent on this header file so they should get recompiled if I change it. They don't however. My Makefile was based on this [article](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_2.html#SEC10).

Note: That it works if I explicitly create a rule for each file, like so:

```
file1.o: header.h
```

---

Update: I added an echo statement after the `$(OBJ): header.h` line to see if `make` was catching it but not doing anything. Unfortunately it doesn't do anything either. So I guess this means that the whole dependency line is not working for some reason.

---

Here is my full Makefile in case I've messed up somewhere:

```
CC   = clang
OPT  = -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g
LIBS = -lm
COMP = $(CC) $(OPT) $(LIBS)
EXEC = checker solver # Binary file(s)

OBJ = magic_check.o magic_io.o simple_checker.o

build: $(EXEC)
    @echo "Building complete."

solver: checker simple_solver.o
    $(COMP) simple_solver.o -o $@

checker: $(OBJ)
    $(COMP) $(OBJ) -o $@

%(OBJ): magic_io.h
    @echo "hello"

magic_check.o: magic_check.h
simple_checker.o: simple_checker.h magic_check.h
simple_solver.o: simple_solver.h

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f checker solver *.o *~ core
    @echo "Cleaning... :)"

rebuild: clean build
    @echo "Rebuilding..."
```

Comment: @user2225104 It's required for my class but I get what you mean.

Comment: Which version of `make` are you using (what is the first line of `make --version`)? Specifically, is it GNU make?

Comment: @Wintermute GNU Make 3.82

Comment: try using `make -n` , it will explain its logic as it goes.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Doesn't print anything. I added an echo statement to the `$(OBJ): header.h` line and that doesn't do anything either. So I guess this means that the whole dependency line is not working for some reason.

Comment: Your `%(OBJS)` have `%` sign when it should have `$`. Aside from that, "works for me". It also shouldn't have any commands in it (your 'echo' isn't harmless here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've booted old debian with make 3.81 and this works flawlessly (as it should be):

```
OBJ:=file1.o file2.o file3.o main.o
TARGET:=prog

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ)

$(OBJ): test.h
```

Results:

```
# make
cc -c -o file1.o file1.c
cc -c -o file2.o file2.c
cc -c -o file3.o file3.c
cc -c -o main.o main.c
cc -o prog file1.o file2.o file3.o main.o
# make
make: `prog' is up to date.
# touch test.h
# make
cc -c -o file1.o file1.c
cc -c -o file2.o file2.c
cc -c -o file3.o file3.c
cc -c -o main.o main.c
cc -o prog file1.o file2.o file3.o main.o
```

The difference between my example and yours, is that your `%(OBJS)` has a `%` sign when it should have `$`. Aside from that, "works for me". It also shouldn't have any commands in it (your 'echo' isn't harmless here).